# Jasper report Iteration(list/ line)

Tags: jasper-reports

I am using main report, in that i want to iterate value like

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
principal amount = 60500.0  rate interest =  15.0  months = 60.0
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
S.No.   Outstanding EMI PrinAmt interest    Total paid
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
1   60500.0 1764.0  1008.0  756.0   1764.0
2   59492.0 1752.0  1008.0  744.0   3516.0
3   58484.0 1739.0  1008.0  731.0   5255.0
4   57476.0 1726.0  1008.0  718.0   6981.0
5   56468.0 1714.0  1008.0  706.0   8695.0
```

... so on..

Now i want to calculate values of these. in jasper report/ iReport Tool.
Please  do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this in number of ways, which way to choose is upon your requirement, supposing that there is a single user for which the results needs to be displayed. Then the iterative statements could be placed in the **detail band** where as the static data i.e the data which is not iterating like principal amt could be placed in the column header

Else, a list could be used assigning the iteration query to the **list**, it could be placed in the detail band or for a single user or record could be placed in the summary band or wherever the data suits your purpose.

Hope that it helps.

Answer (score 0):

For calculation purpose, you can make use of variable in jasper, and put your calculation formula in expression language attribute of that variable.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: Take a variable in jasper ireport and click on it, in its properties bar, go to variable expression and put your calculatation logic like for integer:($F{A}+$F{B})/$F{C} and for string fileds:(new BigDecimal($F{A}).add(new BigDecimal($F{B}))).devide(new BigDecimal($F{C})).